# C# Console App: Why does one PC recognize Ctrl+V as a ConsoleKeyInfo while the other pastes from the Windows Clipboard?

Tags: c#

I discovered a behavior anomaly with my new PC and am unable to determine why.

Just to set the scene, I'm attempting to create a C# console application that functions similarly to an Excel spreadsheet, with the ability to Cut, Copy, Paste, etc.

I have a loop that reads keys till the Escape key is pressed:

```
        private static void RegisterAndExecuteKeyActions()
        {
            ConsoleKeyInfo pressedKey;

            Console.TreatControlCAsInput = true;

            do
            {
                pressedKey = Console.ReadKey(true);

                sheet.Execute(pressedKey);

                sheet.printHandler.PrintSheet();

            } while (pressedKey.Key != ConsoleKey.Escape);
        }
```

and a series of functions that do different things based on the key combinations

```
       public void Execute(ConsoleKeyInfo key)
        {
            switch (key.Key, key.Modifiers)
            {
                case (ConsoleKey.L, ConsoleModifiers.Control):
                    Legend();
                    break;
                case (ConsoleKey.P, ConsoleModifiers.Control):
                    pivotHandler.RunPivot();
                    break;
                case (ConsoleKey.LeftArrow, 0):
                    UpdateCursorPosition(0, -1);
                    break;
                case (ConsoleKey.RightArrow or ConsoleKey.Tab, 0):
                    UpdateCursorPosition(0, 1);
                    break;
                case (ConsoleKey.UpArrow, 0):
                    UpdateCursorPosition(-1, 0);
                    break;
                case (ConsoleKey.DownArrow or ConsoleKey.Enter, 0):
                    UpdateCursorPosition(1, 0);
                    break;
                case (ConsoleKey.Backspace, 0):
                    Backspace();
                    break;
                case (ConsoleKey.Delete, 0):
                    Delete();
                    break;
                case (ConsoleKey.S, ConsoleModifiers.Control):
                    SaveSheet();
                    break;
                case (ConsoleKey.O, ConsoleModifiers.Control):
                    OpenSheet();
                    break;
                case (ConsoleKey.N, ConsoleModifiers.Control):
                    NewSheet();
                    break;
                case (ConsoleKey.X, ConsoleModifiers.Control):
                    Cut();
                    break;
                case (ConsoleKey.C, ConsoleModifiers.Control):
                    Copy();
                    break;
                case (ConsoleKey.V, ConsoleModifiers.Control):
                    Paste();
                    break;
                case (ConsoleKey.F2, 0):
                    movedToAnotherCell = false;
                    break;
                default:
                    AppendKeyToCell(key.KeyChar);
                    break;
            }
        }
```

The paste function should just assign the value to the cell I'm in as I have a variable holding the data I cut/copied.

On my new PC, when I hit CONTROL + V, the desired case (Paste() function) is not reached. Instead, the Windows Clipboard is fed, one character at a time to the Execute(pressedKey) method with the information I copied outside of the console application (if exists) leading to the default case where the chars are appended to the cell.

I tried the following:

-tested the code on 2 other PC's and worked as expected.

-checked the Keyboard layouts

-clipboard settings

Any idea why the new PC is behaving differently?

UPDATE: I managed to stop the issue from happening by right-clicking on the VS console app and going to Settings->Actions and deleting the Paste action.

Still odd that CTRL-X/CTRL-C were treated as an input but CTRL-V wasn't.

Comment: What are the values of `ConsoleKeyInfo` when you press CTRL-V?

Comment: Hi! ConsoleKeyInfo starts with the first character of whatever I have stored in the Windows clipboard. If for example I have "asd" saved in the win clip then ConsoleKeyInfo would start with 'A' with no modifiers followed by S and D. The console will not ask for another input till all the characters ('a', 's', 'd') are exhausted and present in the cell.

Comment: It's almost like Windows is acting like a middle man and when I press CTRL-V my Console App does not get the V Key with a Control modifier but instead is fed whatever I have in the clipboard char by char. I tried with a block of code saved in the clipboard that contains \n at the end of each line and the lines of code were all assigned in different cells, each in the cell beneath it.

Comment: It's acting as if `Console.TreatControlCAsInput = true;` wasn't executed for some reason. Is that property actually set to true after you've set it to true? Also, are you running this from an actual command line, or are you running it from Visual Studio?

Comment: By "new" do you mean "fresh install with the same version of the OS as on other PCs that definitely does not include third-party applications that might install unwanted hooks", or is there some wiggle room there? If possible, test the code in a VM to be sure the behavior replicates under clean circumstances.

Comment: https://www.maketecheasier.com/enable-copy-paste-command-prompt-windows10/

Comment: Are your Windows OS language / keyboard settings set to something other than English?  Ctrl key, Alt key will behave differently for some other languages.

Comment: Could it be that the [cloud clipboard](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/clipboard-in-windows-c436501e-985d-1c8d-97ea-fe46ddf338c6) was enabled?

Comment: @DaveS I'm using ENG US.

Comment: @AndrewMorton I checked and it's disabled.

Comment: Hello @MatthewWatson ! I do believe it's set to true. I first used TreatCOntrolCAsInput when I wrote the copy function to avoid CTRL-C closing my console application. Assuming that it's not closing when I press CTRL-C and the fact that on other machines the code works fine, as intended I'm 90% sure that it's executing. Also, I'm using Visual Studio but I've tested the code in CMD/Power Shell and the same behavior occurs on my new PC. I edited my post and added an update with a fix I found but it's not as elegant as I'd like.